# Missing Update Link to 3.02/3.03 on Dashboard

Tags: automatic-updates

Since upgrading to WP 3.0.1, a couple of my sites no longer display the update link to 3.02/3.03 on the Dashboard or on the Updates page. On one site, I tried re-applying permissions, but this didn't change a thing.

There are no plugins related to 'hiding' update/nag messages.

All the sites have been around since 2.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try flushing out the transient data(options prefixed with `_site_transient_update_` - wp_options table), WP will recreate them for you anyway.

Not always a solution but tends to work for me when i have that problem.

You can do this by adding the following lines to your current theme's **functions.php** (in wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/functions.php).

```
delete_option( '_site_transient_update_core' );
delete_option( '_site_transient_update_themes' );
delete_option( '_site_transient_update_plugins' );
```

**NOTE:** You probably only need the first one, but i usually flush them all if i'm flushing one(can't hurt to have a refresh).

Load any page up once, admin page, post page, whatever, then remove the code(it only needs to run for one page load).

Comment: This is an option from WP or some plugin? Or, are you suggesting a database procedure?

Comment: Updated my answer... ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Did it help resolve your issue?

Comment: Everything is good now.

Comment: Good to hear... :)